# Launching roscore in groovy fails

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I'm testing the new ros-groovy release and for some reason I cannot launch roscore:

I have the following version of ros installed:

```
$ dpkg -l ros-groovy-ros-comm
...
ii  ros-groovy-ros-comm  1.9.39-0precise-2012
```

After sourcing `/opt/ros/groovy/setup.bash` my environment looks like this:

```
env | grep ros
ROS_ROOT=/opt/ros/groovy/share/ros
ROS_PACKAGE_PATH=:/opt/ros/groovy/share:/opt/ros/groovy/stacks
LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/opt/ros/groovy/lib:/opt/halcon/lib/x64-linux2.4-gcc40
CPATH=/opt/ros/groovy/include
PATH=/opt/ros/groovy/bin:/opt/halcon/bin/x64-linux2.4-gcc40:/opt/halcon/FLEXlm/x64-linux2.4-gcc40:/home/rsmits/eclipse:/usr/lib/lightdm/lightdm:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games
PWD=/home/rsmits/ros-groovy-empty
PYTHONPATH=/opt/ros/groovy/lib/python2.7/dist-packages
PKG_CONFIG_PATH=/opt/ros/groovy/lib/pkgconfig
CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH=/opt/ros/groovy
ROS_ETC_DIR=/opt/ros/groovy/etc/roslib
```

launching roscore however fails as follows:

```
$roscore
... logging to /home/rsmits/.ros/log/e2ef1f84-5aff-11e2-98eb-c86000bfbac0/roslaunch-im-desktop-01-6764.log
Checking log directory for disk usage. This may take awhile.
Press Ctrl-C to interrupt
Done checking log file disk usage. Usage is <1GB.

Cannot locate [roslaunch]Invalid <param> tag: Cannot load command parameter [rosversion]: command [rosversion roslaunch] returned with code [1]. 

Param xml is <param command="rosversion roslaunch" name="rosversion"/>
```

executing rosversion roslaunch results in the following error:

```
$rosversion roslaunch
Cannot locate [roslaunch]
```

rospack however indicates that the roslaunch is definitely installed:

```
$rospack find roslaunch 
/opt/ros/groovy/share/roslaunch
```

Does anyone have any idea what I did wrong??

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/51878/launching-roscore-in-groovy-fails/) by [Ruben Smits](https://answers.ros.org/users/350/ruben-smits/) on ROS Answers with karma: 543 on 2013-01-09

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The poblem you have is around rosversion. This should be the correct output:

```
$ rosversion roslaunch
1.9.39
```

rosversion is part of python-rospkg.
So you can initially make sure that this is up to date, and no old easy_install version of rospkg luring in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages

I'd guess an outdated version of rospkg is a likely culprit for your error

---

Originally posted by [KruseT](https://answers.ros.org/users/888/kruset/) with karma: 7848 on 2013-01-09

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Ruben Smits](https://answers.ros.org/users/350/ruben-smits/) on 2013-01-10**:
I cleaned up my /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages and reinstalled python-rospkg(1.0.17-1), I'm still getting the same error for `rosversion roslaunch` though.

**Comment by [Ruben Smits](https://answers.ros.org/users/350/ruben-smits/) on 2013-01-10**:
I also had another version of rosversion lying around in /usr/local/bin which had to be cleaned up too.

**Comment by [Ruben Smits](https://answers.ros.org/users/350/ruben-smits/) on 2013-01-10**:
I also had another version of rosversion lying around in /usr/local/bin which had to be cleaned up too.

**Comment by [Miquel Massot](https://answers.ros.org/users/2515/miquel-massot/) on 2013-01-14**:
Any other idea? It's the same for me, my groovy installation cannot locate roslaunch.

**Comment by [KruseT](https://answers.ros.org/users/888/kruset/) on 2013-01-18**:
Sorry, I did not get mails from answers, so I did not see comments. I am on python-rospkg 1.0.18-1 from apt. @Ruben, does it work foy you now that you cleaned up rosversion as well?